# How can i extract only 2014 from the text "Full Yr.2014 (Weekly)"

Tags: regex, r

I have been able to convert it into `"Full Yr.2014"` but unable to get `2014` at once. I am new to regular expression.

I'm using: `gsub("([0-9]+).*$","\\1",PERIOD)`

Comment: `gsub("[^0-9]","","Full Yr.2014")`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: /([0-9])\w+/g

And also check out this [website](http://regexr.com/), here you can try out different regex expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try `([\d]{4})` as your regex. This regex will search for `four digits`.

Comment: Did you try it? It matches one of these character: `a digit` or `{` or `4` or `}`, that is not what OP wants.